# How can I use pick with optional types in nested typescript

Tags: typescript

I want write typescript

```
  dynamicContent?: {
    data?: {
      attributes?: {
        baccarat?: { title?: string | null; content?: string | null } | null;
        baccaratOnline?: { title?: string | null; content?: string | null } | null;
        casino?: { title?: string | null; content?: string | null } | null;
        casinoOnline?: { title?: string | null; content?: string | null } | null;
        games?: Array<{
          gameUrl?: string | null;
          media: {
            data?: {
              attributes?: {
                url: string;
                alternativeText?: string | null;
                width?: number | null;
                height?: number | null;
              } | null;
            } | null;
          };
        } | null> | null;
      } | null;
    } | null;
  } | null;
};
```

I want to use type games here is what I try

```
  Pick<NonNullable<GetDynamicContentQuery["dynamicContent"]["data"]["attributes"]>, 'games'>
```

it seems like nullable only dynamicContent field am not sure how to nullable all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to not understand the difference between optional and nullable, hence the difference between `undefined` and `null`.

In TypeScript, when you define an optional property, it effectively makes it the type of the property or `undefined`:

```
interface MyInterface {
    myField?: number;
}
```

Will be the effectively the same as:

```
interface MyInterface {
    myField: number | undefined;
}
```

Now, let's talk about `null` and `undefined`. In JavaScript (on top of which TypeScript is built), `undefined` means that something just doesn't exists. It is used when a property of an object doesn't exists:

```js
const obj = { prop1: 'Prop 1', prop2: 'Prop 2', prop3: 123 };
console.log(obj.prop1); // 'Prop 1'
console.log(obj.prop2); // 'Prop 2'
console.log(obj.prop3); // 123
console.log(obj.prop4); // undefined
```

On the other hand, we have `null`. `null` is an actual value in JavaScript, just like any number, string, object or function. It is used to identify that the property / variable, holding the value itself exists, but the value is nothing.

Allowing an optional property to be `null` in TypeScript will cause you issues down the line, so it is recommended that you don't do that, instead, just make the properties optional.

Still, this has already been explained, and much better than I did: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57249968/10566045

Comment: @user8663822 You're welcome. If I've helped you, please mark my answer as the solution

Answer (score 0):

What @TopchetoEU answered is correct and you should probably define the `interface GetDynamicContentQuery` differently. But if you for some reason can not change the definition, here is a solution to access `games` anyway:

```
type DeeplyRemoveNullAndOptional<T> = { 
  [K in keyof T]-?: Exclude<T[K], null | undefined> extends Record<any, any> 
    ? DeeplyRemoveNullAndOptional<Exclude<T[K], null>> 
    : NonNullable<T[K]> 
}

type GamesType = DeeplyRemoveNullAndOptional<
  GetDynamicContentQuery
>["dynamicContent"]["data"]["attributes"]["games"]
```

I was confused why you even needed `Pick`. You can just access `games` directly.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=33&ssc=118&pln=27&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgOITAEQJ4jgW2AQGEB7cCcARQFdptkBvAKGTeQBNcCiyLwAXE1bsOcMHAD8Qlu3biwUYACMakAM7ThcucsQI4UcVsbIwwMABsIW9YtABzZAB9kIGpcsBuZAnKRwW3sQJ1d3T2QAXxc3D28RHWQ9BAMjMAB5EEtQGxkzC2sgpRCY8O9ff0owIsdSuKi6zy8EnQN1UFITfKtc5Dti0Nimiv5qoX7asProqaaWuTaOzOyQXtNzHpqS2fK-Ua3Bsoad5sS2BwIITSEAQSgjbAAeWTPzy4BVKEsDxvjXtnwEA4wDgMnmZzEEhM4NeCiUqg00P%20ZxoX3GwQcp2ROjglkgUDw5gAbhAACoQAAeYz6GN%20WOx7AA7sAOGAABZadz4ZTQOkw-5siDABxs6lcnlQPkMtgzIZ-bGysr0s6RZVyRVxAB8Up0Grm6p1evikWYzDA2AADihMBAIBbLNgAEoQfCkEkAOTiNxAHHSFvM5Fxj1J2oAvExkCIANoAaWQoGQAGsINhSDBkKSALoAWi0AFEKQhLDQOBBg7HMwAaOUxGg%20iAwHIcbWUgIcdTIZ1%20KAcR5wEDYav97DalqSZA2u0O52uj1en1%20gN4SyPAtFktl0kV6tlTWjuRCd3kT2eODKazlmOZ0cms2WlCoS7qUn35Dhyf2p0ut0QE%20Wb2%20v6wCBiu6BYNwhAkJU1B0FAI5RgARFweCQXwARgAhmaIZCcCYYhcIqGoVx4QhFyAuomFAA)