# What is the difference between void, never, null and undefined in TypeScript? When to use each?

Tags: typescript

I would like to know the difference between these four types in **TypeScript** and some practical examples of how to use them. Please don't mark my question as a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5076944/what-is-the-difference-between-null-and-undefined-in-javascript), as I'm talking about TypeScript types **at compile time** and not Javascript values.

Comment: first question is about JS values, not TS types, so I am not sure that it is duplicate

Comment: I agree, I tried to search for this specific question before posting and there are no similar ones.

Answer (score 0):

1. `undefined` means that variable haven't been defined

```
function foo(bar?: number) {
  console.log(bar) // prints undefined
}
```

The `undefined` type is a primitive type that has only one value `undefined`.

2. The `null` value represents the intentional absence of any object value.

The value `null` is written with a literal: `null`. `null` is not an identifier for a property of the global object, like `undefined` can be. Instead, `null` expresses a lack of identification, indicating that a variable points to no object. In APIs, `null` is often retrieved in a place where an object can be expected but no object is relevant.

3. `void` is very similar to `undefined`. It is also type that contains single `undefined` value. But it has special meaning in function return types. And works a little bit different in [type compatibility](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html?#any-unknown-object-void-undefined-null-and-never-assignability)

The intent of `void` is that a function's return value will not be observed. This is very different from will be `undefined`

4. `never` means that a function with this return type can never return normally at all. This means either throwing an exception or failing to terminate. `never` is type contains no values