# how to read object by object in nodejs without knowing its structure from a json file

Tags: json, node.js

my json file data:

```
[
    {"name":"a","queryname":"Query_1","type":"user","context":"novell","searchsubcontainer":false},
    {"name":"aa","queryname":"Query_2","type":"user","context":"novell","searchsubcontainer":true},
    {"name":"admin","queryname":"Query_3","type":"user","context":"microfocus","searchsubcontainer":true},
    {"name":"*","type":"","context":"novell","searchsubcontainer":true,"queryname":"default"},
    {"name":"John","type":"user","context":"novell","searchsubcontainer":true,"auxClasses":[],"advancedFlag":true,"advancedFilter":{"condition":"and","rules":[{"field":"city","operator":"equals","value":"provo"},{"field":"personalTitle","operator":"equals","value":"employee"}]},"queryname":"john"},
    {"name":"jack","type":"user","context":"novell","searchsubcontainer":true,"auxClasses":[],"advancedFlag":true,"advancedFilter":{"condition":"and","rules":[{"field":"city","operator":"equals","value":"utah"},{"field":"personalTitle","operator":"equals","value":"manager"}]},"queryname":"jack"},
    {"name":"Martin","type":"user","context":"novell","searchsubcontainer":true,"queryname":"martin"},
    {"name":"Luke","type":"user","context":"novell","searchsubcontainer":true,"queryname":"luke"},
    {"name":"Anay","type":"user","context":"novell","searchsubcontainer":true,"queryname":"Anay"}
]
```

how do i read these data in nodejs and delete a particular entry in the file using the attribute `queryname`. is there any way to read object by object from the json array ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use of the operator [delete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8945276/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-delete-operator-in-javascript) to remove a specific key from a json.

```js
const json = [{
    "name": "a",
    "queryname": "Query_1",
    "type": "user",
    "context": "novell",
    "searchsubcontainer": false
  },
  {
    "name": "aa",
    "queryname": "Query_2",
    "type": "user",
    "context": "novell",
    "searchsubcontainer": true
  },
  {
    "name": "admin",
    "queryname": "Query_3",
    "type": "user",
    "context": "microfocus",
    "searchsubcontainer": true
  },
  {
    "name": "*",
    "type": "",
    "context": "novell",
    "searchsubcontainer": true,
    "queryname": "default"
  },
  {
    "name": "John",
    "type": "user",
    "context": "novell",
    "searchsubcontainer": true,
    "auxClasses": [],
    "advancedFlag": true,
    "advancedFilter": {
      "condition": "and",
      "rules": [{
        "field": "city",
        "operator": "equals",
        "value": "provo"
      }, {
        "field": "personalTitle",
        "operator": "equals",
        "value": "employee"
      }]
    },
    "queryname": "john"
  },
  {
    "name": "jack",
    "type": "user",
    "context": "novell",
    "searchsubcontainer": true,
    "auxClasses": [],
    "advancedFlag": true,
    "advancedFilter": {
      "condition": "and",
      "rules": [{
        "field": "city",
        "operator": "equals",
        "value": "utah"
      }, {
        "field": "personalTitle",
        "operator": "equals",
        "value": "manager"
      }]
    },
    "queryname": "jack"
  },
  {
    "name": "Martin",
    "type": "user",
    "context": "novell",
    "searchsubcontainer": true,
    "queryname": "martin"
  },
  {
    "name": "Luke",
    "type": "user",
    "context": "novell",
    "searchsubcontainer": true,
    "queryname": "luke"
  },
  {
    "name": "Anay",
    "type": "user",
    "context": "novell",
    "searchsubcontainer": true,
    "queryname": "Anay"
  }
];

json.forEach((x) => {
  delete x.queryname;
});

console.log(json);
```

Comment: it is saying .forEach() is not a function in nodejs

Comment: So the variable you are trying to apply `.forEach()` to is not an array