# How to modify tree object by property?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have an object with type:

```
export interface TreeNode extends ITreeNode {
   name: string,
   children:  TreeNode[],
   show?: boolean;
}
```

I need to reduce this object by property `show` and return a new tree where `show` is `true` or `undefined`.

I have tried this:

```
  function prepareNodes(source: TreeNode) {
        if (source.show!== undefined || source.show == false) delete source;
      if (source.children) {
        source.children.forEach((child: TreeNode) => {
          this.prepareNodes(child);
        });
      }
  }
```

Also I tried:

```
function prepareNodes(source: any) {
      if (source.show !== undefined && source.show === false) source = null;
      if (source.children) {
        source.children = source.children.filter((child: any) => child.show== undefined || child.show === true);
        source.children.forEach((child: any) => prepareNodes(child));
      }
  }
```

Comment: Updated my question

Comment: What do you expect the output to be? What is the output the function is giving at the moment?

Comment: `show` cannot be `undefined` by your own definition of it.

Comment: that makes it worse!! Now your entire premise of reducing is based upon an optional property - not one that will always either be true, false or undefined. You've created a case where `show` may not even exist but not accounted for that.

Comment: I know, it is, but is my case, I should check on undefined/true/false as I posted

Comment: Can you please post some sample data?

Comment: Is your whole issue that you're doing `delete source` instead of `delete source.show`?  Are you tying to modify the existing tree or produce a new tree?  Are you trying to have the output tree known to be `true | undefined` by the compiler? Or is `boolean | undefined` acceptable as the output type?

Comment: [`delete source` does not do what you think it does](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8945276/215552)...

Comment: Ideally you'd post a [mcve] suitable for dropping into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground](https://tsplay.dev/zwOoyw) where the issue you're having is clearly demonstrated and no extraneous issues are present (no typos, no undeclared or unimported things).  Right now there's not quite enough for me to feel confident answering.

Comment: So, I see only way to create a new tree after filtrering

Comment: Oof, `source.show!== undefined || source.show == false` is.. weird. If `source.show` is `true` or `false`, that evaluates to `true`.  If `source.show` is `undefined`, that evaluates to `false`.  So you're checking if `source.show` is either `true` or `false` for some reason, and not `undefined`.  What is happening here?   I strongly suggest you modify the example code so that it represents what you're trying to do as closely as you can, and show enough use cases so others can figure out what constitutes success.  And what's `registry`?  I think we need some cleanup here.

Comment: `Undefined` is in casw when there is a property in object, false can be when `show: false` and `show: true.`

Comment: I'm not following, sorry.  Could you be more explicit in the text of your question?  And again, a [mcve] is crucial here.  At this point I don't even understand if you want `show: true` in the input to become `show: true` in the output.  I was assuming you wanted `true` to become `true`, and `false`-or-`undefined` to become `undefined`. Like [this code](https://tsplay.dev/PmLoeN). Now I'm thoroughly confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently my assumption is that you want to produce a new tree containing just those nodes of the original tree where the `show` property is either `true` or `undefined` for that node *and all ancestor nodes*.  So if `show` is false on any node, the output tree will not contain that node or any subtree of that node.

I also assume that it's possible for the root node to have `show` of `false`, in which case the whole tree might end up `undefined`.  You can't set modify an object to become `undefined`; you can change its contents, but you can't delete it.  So I'm not going to present anything that tries to modify the original tree.  I won't touch the original tree.  Instead I will produce a completely new tree.

Here goes:

```
const defined = <T,>(x: T | undefined): x is T => typeof x !== "undefined";

function filterTree(source: TreeNode): TreeNode | undefined {
  if (source.show === false) return;
  return {
    name: source.name,
    show: source.show,
    children: source.children.map(filterTree).filter(defined)
  }
}
```

The `filterTree()` function will return `undefined` if the argument node's `show` property is exactly `false` (and not `undefined`). Otherwise, it produces a new node with the same `name` and `show`, and whose `children` property is what you get when you call `filterTree()` (recursively) on each of the original node's `children`, and then `filter` out any `undefined` nodes.

I'm using a [user-defined type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards) function called `defined` to let the compiler know that the `filter`ing takes an array of  `TreeNode | undefined` and produces an array of `TreeNode`, eliminating any `undefined` entries.

Hopefully this meets your use cases; please test it out on whatever data you have and check, because the question unfortunately did not include such data.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCpQhAcgewCYoDeAUMsiHALYQBcyAzmFKAOYA0pyCAFsADZ4MIOuky4CAbQC6HMvW44A7gH46AIxw4+EOCADcxAL7FiCHCEbICMUBDzIAvMgA8qNgD4AFAA8RyAD7IAK4g1rZ4AJR03sjA9GiO7shgAJ4ADhA4MMgxAIQOTgBEIWEgdoUGxDAhCGDA5sg2fJBQohCe9DhBUEgiGNj4EFFo-eIogSUQNmX2JGTA2R1dPRAAdPJKjgWNcHz0Q8gYYN36nEcnyHNk5FS0DMtIqxTUstcbinSd3Y-vr2Q8-EEEGE92+awBAiEq0ocDSniaLTaEVWCOgnlKdginGMxhMpnMllAwDAbT6YkGjkunGed0KUE0YEKr3edCYQQgrwhQJBEk4ZEIN2odEKXIAjEyGAoPjs9hyuLxIcC6NJkIY-pdBbSuQAmCUs4KhKbhNjywFCZVSVXqgU04VcgDMEq55uQKuMZCkRkqZgsWjWfBwLE8ACkAMoAeSw6yYrAWKU8RJJ-RNk2mdhN2oiWIA9AAqKlkQo0wrC+k4RmvQrvEsy-aV53Amu864FlvIIu3GsihV4cXqwvV1lQdn99sNkBNz0ttV81stjvULs6pmzwvjyezmctq7z4t2nuO0fds2Ni2bziewzIXPZkw+yx1FjcRH9Smo1r9BMgYlI70Ev2rAGQZhpG0bMCALBxp4j7PtAbQpoaaZ4BmWZAA)

Comment: Could I use this: `return {
    ...source,
    children: source.children.map(filterTree).filter(defined)
  }`?

Comment: Yes, if you want.

Comment: How to post link from typescript playground? it is so long

Comment: Where do you want to post it? You can put it in your question with the link syntax `[text](url)`.  Or if you install the Link Shortener plugin on the Playground you can generate short links for them, but I don't know how to walk you through that process over the internet.

Comment: Look it does not work for property registry: https://stackblitz.com/edit/xy4wiq?file=index.ts

Comment: Can you modify that code to spell out exactly what you expect to see and where?  All I see is "Import error, can't find file:"

Comment: I try to show nodes where registry is true or undefined. The same situation

Comment: Check out this: https://typescript-isam5f.stackblitz.io

Comment: This node with `id": "37_1",` should not be in result object

Comment: all I see at that link is "starting dev server". I don't understand why `37_1` should not be in there; I am showing all with `true` or `undefined` and suppressing `false`.  `37_1` is not defined, so it's shown.  `undefined` makes it shown.    I need clear instructions in English before I can continue to engage here.

Comment: Let me check please, probably I disinformation you