# Javascript - Initialize array with nulls

Tags: javascript, arrays

In Javascript, why is

```
var myArray = new Array(3);
```

different from:

```
var otherArray = [null, null, null];
```

?

Obs: `(myArray == otherArray)` returns `false`.

And also, how can I get a variable like `otherArray`, which is an array full of 'nulls`, but with whatever size i'd like?

**Obs**

```
[undefined, undefined, undefined]
```

is also not equal to myArray.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24038939/strange-array-behavior-in-javascript something very similar

Comment: Two objects are only equal if they are the same object. Since in your case `otherArray` is not the same array as `myArray` they can't be equal.

Comment: Because `null` is not the undefined value in javascript: `undefined` is. The first one is filled with `undefined`.

Comment: it is still not equal if I create an array [undefined, undefined, undefined]

Comment: `obj1 == obj2` will always be `false`, `[1] == [1]; // false`

Comment: similar objects are never equal

Comment: I understand that now. But how can I create the array full of nulls for any size?

Comment: the way you created the  `otherArray` in your question

Comment: ok, then I'll have to iterate if there's no other way.

Comment: you could use the deep-equal npm package

Answer (score 172, accepted):

With **EcmaScript 6 (ES2105)**, creating an array containing `five nulls` is as easy as this:

```js
const arr = new Array(5).fill(null);
```

[MDN Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill)

Comment: This should be the accepted answer at this year my friend!

Comment: You should use this method.

Comment: Be careful though, 'fill' is not supported in IE

Comment: This is the way

Answer (score 5):

This `var myArray = new Array(3);` will create an empty array. Hence, for this reason, `myArray` and `otherArray` are different arrays. Furthermore, even if they had the same values, three `undefined` values, the arrays wouldn't be the same. An array is an object and the variable `myArray` holds a reference to that object. Two objects with the same values aren't the same.

For instance,

```
var a = new Object();
var b = new Object();
console.log(a===b); // outputs false.
```

In addition to this:

```
var customerA = { name: "firstName" };
var customerB = { name: "firstName" };
console.log(customerA===customerB); // outputs false.
```

**Update**

Furthermore, in the case of `var myArray = new Array(3)` even the indices aren't initialized, as correctly Paul pointed out in his comment.

If you try this:

```
var array = [1,2,3];
console.log(Object.keys(array));
```

you will get as an output:

```
["1","2","3"];
```

While if you try this:

```
var array = new Array(3);
console.log(Object.keys(array));
```

you will get as output:

```
[]
```

Comment: A link to a resource about sparse arrays would make it a complete answer I guess :) (about Array iteration methods)

Comment: It's more than the items are just _undefined_, the indices aren't initialised either;

Comment: *"new Array(3); will create an array with three elements that are undefined"* not quite true. It creates empty array, without any values at all, even undefined (so called "holes"). it's just reading missing indexes returns `undefined`.

Comment: @Christos `var myArray = new Array(3); will create an empty array` not quite true, should be array of length three having all empty values..

Comment: @dfsq `var array = new Array(3); console.log(array.length);` This outputs 3. So how the `array` is empty?

Comment: Christos.. read my comment.. array of length three but all empty values.. i.e no value in it. Not an empty array

Comment: @Christos It doesn't have nor indexes nor values, only holes. It's like allocated space. In general `new Array(number)` has little useful application.

Comment: @Christos I always find this easiest to understand as `0 in new Array(1); // false`

Comment: Or `Object.keys(new Array(1))` => `[]`, but `Object.keys(new Array(1,2))` => `["0", "1"]`.

Comment: @dfsq Nice approach. I didn't think it. I will include also to my post.

Answer (score 4):

The first point to note is that if you want to compare two `Arrays` or any other `Object`, you either have to loop over them or serialize them as comparing references will always give `false`

---

> How can I get a variable like otherArray, which is an array full of 'nulls', but with whatever size I'd like?

Here is an alternative method for creating *Arrays* with a default value for its items and all indices initialised:

```
function createArray(len, itm) {
    var arr1 = [itm],
        arr2 = [];
    while (len > 0) {
        if (len & 1) arr2 = arr2.concat(arr1);
        arr1 = arr1.concat(arr1);
        len >>>= 1;
    }
    return arr2;
}
```

Now,

```
createArray(9, null);
// [null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null]
```

Comment: I do not understand why you wrote such a complicated function. I tested this one
    `function createArray2(len, itm) { var arr = []; while (len > 0) { arr.push(itm); len--;} return arr;}`
I ran tests using console.time in Chrome and the results of `createArray(10000, null)` and `createArray(1000000, null)` in a 1000 forloop are: 143.964ms/98.495ms and 20114.130ms/16686.080ms the faster always being my function... Did I miss something ?

Answer (score 3):

I've did some research and it turned out that the `Array(length).fill(null)` it not the best solution in terms of performance.

The best performance showed:

```js
const nullArr = Array(length)
for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
  nullArr[i] = null
}
```

Just look at this:

```js
const Benchmark = require('benchmark')
const suite = new Benchmark.Suite

const length = 10000

suite
  .add('Array#fill', function () {
    Array(length).fill(null)
  })
  .add('Array#for', function () {
    const nullArr = Array(length)
    for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
      nullArr[i] = null
    }
  })

  .on('cycle', function (event) {
    console.log(String(event.target))
  })
  .on('complete', function () {
    console.log('Fastest is ' + this.filter('fastest').map('name'))
  })

  .run({ async: true })
```

It shows the following results:

```sh
Array#fill x 44,545 ops/sec ±0.43% (91 runs sampled)
Array#for x 78,789 ops/sec ±0.35% (94 runs sampled)
Fastest is Array#for
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also try `[...new Array(76)]` to generate 76 undefineds.

```js
console.log(
  [...new Array(76)]
)
```

Or to fill with `null`.

```js
console.log(
  [...new Array(76).fill(null)]
)
```

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me

```
const bucket = [Array(9).fill(null)]
```

Comment: Answer needs supporting information
Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).