# Issue creating empty object null

Tags: javascript

`element.innerHTML = ''`

*when getting objects in an array, remember that its an array methofrememebr that its an ARRAY method

```
   ex : array.forEach(element/or obj) depending if the obj is nested in the array
   dont forget .innerText = element
   if array in obj do res.nameofarray.forEach
prevetdefault is a method()

.value
```

This is a question regarding javascript

````
likeButton.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    let currentLikes = parseInt(likes.innerText)
    currentLikes++
    likes.innerText = currentLikes
})```
````

Comment: Can you reword this? I have no idea what your asking, what is "methofrememebr"? And what is your is your first example?

Comment: I would try updating the question, its not clear.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure what your asking, but creating an array with `arrayName = [' ', ' ']` makes array have the values of spaces, not null's. If you want an array filled with null you have to create it with `arrayName = [null, null]` (you can also make an empty array and fill it with null's as shown here: [Javascript - Initialize array with nulls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27841362/javascript-initialize-array-with-nulls))