# What happens when you assign undefined in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Consider the following code:

```
var x = undefined;
```

It's a self-contradicting line of code. Is x defined or not? Do implementations of JavaScript remove the variable `x` from memory, or do they assign it the value `undefined`?

Comment: my brain has just segfaulted

Comment: possible duplicate of [Setting a variable to undefined](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2235622/setting-a-variable-to-undefined)

Comment: Different question about the same topic.

Comment: `undefined` is just a data type/value in JS, similar to `null`. There can certainly be confusion between saying "the variable is undefined" and " the variable has the value undefined".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a difference between a variable being *undeclared* and being *undefined*:

```
var x;     //x is equal to *undefined*
alert(y);  //error, y is undeclared
```

This isn't self-contradicting, but it *is* redundant:

```
var x = undefined;
```

Think of `undefined` as simply the value a variable has when it hasn't been initialized – or the value an object property has when it hasn't been initialized *or* declared.

Comment: It's worth also noting that the *undefined* value is returned when accessing •undeclared* properties.